# "With what" question!

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Can you give me the answer for this interrogative sentence?

> "**With** what are you marked?"
>
> "I am marked with white powder."

Is it grammatically correct? I have seen questions such as "to whom are you talking?" But this is the first time I see the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's grammatically okay to say so but remember that putting the word with at the end of the sentence would be better but as i said it's okay.see
With what are you painting the house? or What are you painting the house with?
as you see second one is more used in English.

Comment: Thanks! I just fixed that question, it's from a children book written by Indian. Can you give me more example from other high-quality websites?

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatically correct, strictly speaking you should never end a sentence with a preposition. However, in general speech native speakers wouldn't usually use the "With what are you marked?" construction. We would say "What are you marked with?" even though it's incorrect grammar.

Comment: Can you explain it? I want a formal and grammatically correct since this is a book for children, so which sentence I should choose? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

"What are you marked with?"
"White powder."

I believe that's what you're looking for. I may be wrong.

Comment: No, "with what" is perhaps and archaic way to start a sentence, but it is grammatical, so no transformation is necessary.